# Customizing bootstrap 5 button colors and properties in it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I've created my `custom.scss` in my project, and done this:

```
$primary: #e84c22;

$theme-colors: (
  primary: $primary,
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

So far, the color is like this:

[image: button]

I am not satisfied with the text inside the `btn-primary` class. By default it's dark and regular font.
I want to change it to **white and bold text** without adding `text-light` and `fw-bold` classes to the button element.
I expected it to be like this:

[image: bold button]

How can I do that by modifying the `custom.scss`?

**extra information:**
Unlike `btn-danger`
[image: btn-danger]
It is white text by default. There must be a function to modify the text color according to the color brightness in bootstrap.

Comment: You changed background color and complaining about the text color. Perhaps, you need to change the text color too, e.g. `$btn-primary-color: #fff`? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L156

Comment: @Anonymous I'll elaborate the question. It's because another color has different properties by default.

Comment: @Anonymous - there is no `$btn-primary-color` in Bootstrap 5.  And the `bootstrap-sass` project you're linking to is the old Bootstrap 3 conversion from LESS to SCSS.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> "There must be a function to modify the text color according to the
> color brightness in bootstrap."

Yes, it's using the [WCAG 2.0 algorithm explained here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#color-contrast). The red color you're using is just light enough to flip the text color to dark according to the WCAG algorithm.

Buttons are created by mixins (see: [Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#mixins) in the docs).  In this case the 3rd parameter of the `button-variant` mixin `$color` is defined as:

```
$color: color-contrast($background, $color-contrast-dark, $color-contrast-light, $min-contrast-ratio)
```

So the button's color is either `$color-contrast-dark` or `$color-contrast-light`, depending on the WCAG 2.0 calculation using the `$min-contrast-ratio`.

Therefore, making the custom red color color *slightly* darker will flip the text color to white...

```
$primary: #d73b11;

@import "bootstrap";
```

***Or,*** you can use the original custom color and force white bold text on `btn-primary` like this...

```
$primary: #e84c22;

@import "bootstrap";

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;    
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/EYeDsHlr1z)

***Or,***

You can set a lower value on the `$min-contrast-ratio` variable (3, 4.5, and 7 are the acceptable values) as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68303393/171456)

---

Also note that the way you're re-defining the theme-color map is wiping out all the other theme colors. You only need to change the value of $primary to change the primary theme color.

Comment: `$min-contrast-ratio` was a huge help

Comment: It would be great to have an example with `$min-contrast-ratio`. Simply chaging it or setting `$primary: #000;` shows a black button with black text