# Customize bootstrap 5 text color contrast in button

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I am customizing bootstrap 5 using [bootstrap.build](https://bootstrap.build/app). So far, I had no problem.
[image]
[image]

[image]

But, when I switch to *react* project, things gone wrong. The text inside the button become black. same goes to the outline button when on hover.
[image]

[image]

All I did was customizing the `.scss` file such as this:

```
$orange: #e84c22;
$primary: $orange;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

What is wrong?

My aim here is to change these button with the exact `#e84c22` color to display white text only using `btn btn-outline-primary` and `btn btn-primary` class.

I've tried changing `$yiq-contrasted-threshold` to `200` but it doesn't change anything.

So, what is the difference between Bootstrap in react and in bootstrap.build? what's happening behind it?

here's example project in codesanbox.io. please review it and tell me what did I do wrong.
[image: Edit sparkling-paper-5tvvc]

Comment: it has to do with `color-contrast`.it auto detects and decides which color to use for text

Comment: @Apostolos Correct, I am aware of that. But, why does it differs when I imported it to react? and how to fix this? I've been searching for this thing like almost a week.

Comment: sorry, i saw that you dont want to use selectors. my solution was based on `button-outline-variant` and selectors

Comment: can you add the same non-react project on sandbox?

Comment: @Apostolos here's another [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-express-pug-bootstrap-sass-jw721?file=/index.js). The result's just the same. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67958494/6274120) answer seems relevant, but I just don't know how to implement it in `.scss` file.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It appears from the checking the source that bootstrap.build/app is using Bootstrap 4, *not* Bootstrap 5. The color contrast logic has changed from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5, and the color contrast threshold is very different.

Bootstrap 4 used the YIQ color space...

```
// The yiq lightness value that determines when the lightness of color changes from "dark" to "light". Acceptable values are between 0 and 255.
$yiq-contrasted-threshold:  150 !default;
```

Bootstrap 5 uses the [WCAG 2.0 algorithm](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#color-contrast)

```
// The contrast ratio to reach against white, to determine if color changes from "light" to "dark". Acceptable values for WCAG 2.0 are 3, 4.5 and 7.
// See https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast
$min-contrast-ratio:   4.5 !default;
```

Comparing the 2 versions, and the color logic:

[Using the 4.x color contrast logic to change $primary to #e84c22](https://www.codeply.com/p/4BAJTBWrbr) - results in **light** text color

[Using the 5.x color contrast logic to change $primary to #e84c22](https://www.codeply.com/p/PALiKIfMIc) - results in **dark** text color

---

So, your Bootstrap 5 React SASS customizations are working as expected, and bootstrap.build is still using older 4.x.

To get the light text color in Bootstrap 5 (with React), you could change the default value of the `$min-contrast-ratio` variable...

For example, changing $min-contrast-ratio from 4.5 to 3 makes the text color light in contrast to `#e84c22`:

```
$min-contrast-ratio: 3;
$orange: #e84c22;
$primary: $orange;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

https://codeply.com/p/Z1tOoBclnH

As explained in the Bootstrap 5 SASS "the acceptable values for WCAG 2.0 are 3, 4.5 and 7". Alternatively, you can use the 5.x solutions described in my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952873/customizing-bootstrap-5-button-colors-and-properties-in-it/67958494#67958494). If you're looking to further customize Bootstrap, [themestr.app](https://themestr.app/theme) (note: I'm the creator) has been updated with Bootstrap 5.x.