# Change primary color in boostrap SCSS but keep the other color untouched

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, variables, sass, colors, bootstrap-5

In non-styled boostrap a button may look like this:

[image: non-styled button]

If I change the primary color in the scss and build the assets, for example to this color: `#B40064` by setting this code in the scss file

```
$primary: #B40064;
```

I get this, which is correct:

[image: styled-button-white-letters]

But if I use a brighter color like this one: `#e70080` then the text turns black instead of white:

```
$primary: #e70080;
```

[image: styled-button-dark-letters]

## Problem

I'd want that the text color stays white.

How can I do this in the "general variable setup" that keeps a consistent design for all items?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize bootstrap 5 text color contrast in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298372/customize-bootstrap-5-text-color-contrast-in-button)

Comment: Right @isherwood => `"devDependencies": { "bootstrap": "^5.2.3", },`

Comment: Please **tag** your Bootstrap version.