# svelte customising bootstrap5 using sass

Tags: sass, svelte, bootstrap-5

I am new to scss and I am trying to make use of bootstrap 5. so far I have managed to define a primary color, i seem to have run into this problem here [Customizing bootstrap 5 button colors and properties in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952873/customizing-bootstrap-5-button-colors-and-properties-in-it) the background is red but the color of the text is black and i cannot seem to change it

This is what I have in `src/main.scss`

```sass
// Variable overrides for bootstrap
$primary: #fa2152;
// $secondary: ;
// $success: 
// $info: 
// $warning: 
// $danger: 
$light: #d8d8d8;
// $dark: 

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
}

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

my rollup file

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";


const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;
const site = process.env.SITE || 'defaults';

function serve() {
    let server;

    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: !production,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        replace({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
            'process.env.SITE': JSON.stringify(site),
        }),
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
                sourceMap: !production,
                // defaults: {
                //  style: 'scss'
                //   },
                postcss: {
                    plugins: [
                    //  require("tailwindcss"),
                     require("autoprefixer"),
                    ],
                  },
            }),
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            },
            emitCss: true,
        }),
        scss({watch: 'src', output: 'public/build/bootstrap.css'}),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css'}),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production
        }),
        json(),
        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

my public/index.html contains

```
<link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bootstrap.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>

    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
```

I want to make the color of the button white.

in `src/main.ts` i do

```ts
import "./main.scss";

import App from "./App.svelte";

const app = new App({
  target: document.body,
  props: {},
});

export default app;
```