# Change text color of custom Bootstrap button in SCSS

Tags: bootstrap-5

I want to change the text-color of a custom Bootstrap 5 button to white. I couldn't find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67958494/126833).

```
$myProject-colors: (
  "main": red,
);

@import "functions";
@import "variables";

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $myProject-colors);

@import "bootstrap";
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-main">Main Color - the text of this is still black</button>
```

bootstrap-5.2.0-beta1

Comment: It should suffice to add the **text-white** class to the button.

Comment: That works - but I am trying to figure out a way to 'extend' bootstrap.

Comment: After @import "variables" the assignment of $theme-colors has no effect. You need to define it completely **before** "variables". That way you'll be able to add more colors.

Comment: Im not over-writing it - Im using `map-merge`

Comment: Sure, but after being defined in **variables**, the map $theme-colors is not used anymore, so there's no point in changing it after. It's only used in **variables** when used to build the $theme-colors-rgb map and then the $utilities-colors.

Comment: But in bootstrap.scss, `@import "maps"` comes after `@import "variables"` and `$theme-colors-rgb` and `$utilities-colors` are defined in _maps.scss

Comment: Ok - so this has changed from bootstrap 5.1 to 5.2
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v5.1.3/scss/_variables.scss
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v5.2.0-beta1/scss/_variables.scss